# How to pull xcom value from other task instance in the same DAG run (not the most recent one)?

Tags: airflow

I have 3 DAG runs:

1. DAGR 1 executed at 2019-02-13 16:00:00
2. DAGR 2 executed at 2019-02-13 17:00:00
3. DAGR 3 executed at 2019-02-13 18:00:00

In a task instance `X` of `DAGR 1` I want to get xcom value of task instance `Y`. I did this:

```
kwargs['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='Y')
```

I expected to get value of xcom from task instance `Y` in `DAGR 1`. Instead I got from `DAGR 3`.

From Airflow documentation

> If `xcom_pull` is passed a single string for `task_ids`, then the most recent XCom value from that task is returned; ...

1. Why Airflow `xcom_pull` return the most recent xcom value?
2. What if I want to pull from the same DAG run?

Answer (score 1):

This asnwers your question [How to pull xcom value from other task instance in the same DAG run (not the most recent one)? ] 
See the **example** below :

```
t1 = SomeOperator(
        task_id='Your_t1_Task_ID',
        xcom_push = True,
        ...
        ...
        dag=dag)

    def get_records(**kwargs):
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Your_t1_Task_ID')
        string_to_print = 'Value in xcom is: {}'.format(xcom)
        #string_to_print holds that value, you can also print it in the logs
        logging.info(string_to_print)

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='records',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=get_records,
        dag=dag)

    t1 >> t2
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you are looking for [`include_prior_dates` param](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3179) of `xcom_pull()` method
- Do note that it will return entire **history of `Xcom`s** (`python` `list`, *each item being one `xcom` record*) pushed by the given `task` (filtered by `task_id`(s)) and then you will have to manually **filter-out the desired `xcom`** using [`execution_date` field](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L4735)
- It maybe difficult to supply exact `execution_date` for filtering; for that, see how they've implemented [`execution_delta` and `execution_date_fn` params](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.py#L39) in `ExternalTaskSensor`