# How can one set a variable for use only during a certain dag_run

Tags: airflow

How do I set a variable for use during a particular dag_run.  I'm aware of setting values in xcom, but not all the operators that I use has xcom support.  I also would not like to store the value into the Variables datastore, in case another dag run begins while the current one is running, that need to store different values.

Comment: Your question is **unclear**; please **elaborate your question** with better explanation of *use-case* / *problem-statement*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear, but from whatever I can infer, I'll try to clear your doubts

---

> not all the operators that I use has xcom support

Apparently you've mistaken `xcom` with some other construct because `xcom` feature is [part of `TaskInstance`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2024) and the functions [`xcom_push()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3159) and [`xcom_pull()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3173) are **defined in `BaseOperator` itself** (which is the parent of all `Airflow` `operator`s)

---

> I also would not like to store the value into the Variables datastore,
>   in case another dag run begins while the current one is running, that
>   need to store different values.

It is straightforward (and no-brainer) to **separate-out `Variable`s on per-`DAG` basis** (see [point (6)](https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f)); but yes for different `DagRun`s of a single `DAG`, this kind of isolation would be a challenge. I can think of `xcom` to be the easiest workaround for this. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668287/3679900) for some insights on usage of `Xcom`s.

---

Additionally, if you want to **manipulate `Variable`s** (or any other `Airflow` *model*) **at runtime** (though I would recommend you to avoid it particularly for `Variable`s), `Airflow` also gives completely liberty to exploit the underlying `SQLAlchemy ORM` *framework* for that. You can take inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53740885/3679900).

Comment: Great answer. So currently, I've figured out to use Xcom, also within a file which needs string substitution thru macros, and grabbing values from xcom from the `ti` variable.  So I'm interested in being able to make use of the xcom variable values during the definition of the task itself, where it instantiates an obj of the operator, where within one of the arguments, I'd like to access the xcom variables to calculate something.

Comment: **@Joyce** For that you have 3 options **[1]** Use [`context["task_instance"]`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms) **[2]** Use [`BaseOperator.pull_xcom(..)`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3173) **[3]** Directly exploit `SQLAlchemy` ORM like [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L1166). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061162/3679900)

Comment: **@Joyce**, correction here: for your query `..being able to make use of the xcom variable values during the definition of the task itself, where it instantiates an obj of the operator..`, this is only possible via method **[3]** above: using `SQLAlchemy` ORM