# Airflow xcom_pull is not giving the data of same upstream task instance run, instead gives most recent data

Tags: python, airflow

I am creating an Airflow @daily DAG, It has an upstream task `get_daily_data` of BigQueryGetDataOperator which fetches data based on execution_date and on downstream dependent task (PythonOperator) uses above date based data via xcom_pull. When I run the airflow backfill command, the downstream task `process_data_from_bq` where I am doing xcom_pull, it gets the recent data only not the data of the same execution date which the downstream task is expecting. 
Airfow documentation is saying if we pass *If xcom_pull is passed a single string for task_ids, then the most recent XCom value from that task is returned*
However its not saying how to get the data of same instance of the DAG execution.

I went through the one same question [How to pull xcom value from other task instance in the same DAG run (not the most recent one)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666217/how-to-pull-xcom-value-from-other-task-instance-in-the-same-dag-run-not-the-mos) however, the one solution given there is what I am already doing. but seems its not the correct answer.

DAG defination:

```
dag = DAG(
    'daily_motor',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily'
)

#This task creates data in a BigQuery table based on execution date
extract_daily_data  = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='daily_data_extract',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    allow_large_results=True,
    sql=policy_by_transaction_date_sql('{{ ds }}'), 
    destination_dataset_table='Test.daily_data_tmp',
    dag=dag)


get_daily_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
    task_id='get_daily_data',
    dataset_id='Test',
    table_id='daily_data_tmp',
    max_results='10000',
    dag=dag

)


#This is where I need to pull the data of the same execution date/same instance of DAG run not the most recent task run

def process_bq_data(**kwargs):
    bq_data = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids = 'get_daily_data')
    #This bq_data is most recent one not of the same execution date
    obj_creator = IibListToObject()
    items = obj_creator.create(bq_data, 'daily')
    save_daily_date_wise(items)


process_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id='process_data_from_bq',
    python_callable=process_bq_data,
    provide_context=True,
    dag = dag
)

get_daily_data.set_upstream(extract_daily_data)
process_data.set_upstream(get_daily_data)
```

Comment: I am wondering about your statement - It has an upstream task get_daily_data of BigQueryGetDataOperator which fetches data based on execution_date. I do not see execution_date or {{ds}} either in the source_code for the operator or in the arguments passed to the operator. Are you sure it fetches data based on execution_date?

Comment: @nightgaunt yes it passes the {{d}} in the sql parameter in BigQueryOperator. What this operator does is.. fetches the data based on execution date and dumps to a temp table and in the next dependent task this data is extracted. Which is basically BigQueryGetDataOperator

Comment: Can you try adding `include_prior_dates=False` to your xcom_pull function? If it does not work can you try `include_prior_dates=True` and share the output?

Answer (score 2):

You must be receiving latest Xcom value. You need to also be sure that values are actually from same execution_date as it is supposed :

```
:param include_prior_dates:
```

If False, only XComs from the current
            execution_date are returned. 
If True, XComs from previous dates
            are returned as well.

Comment: since it was causing issue in backfill only and after putting a lot of effort when could not find any concrete solution, I did use depends_on_past flag to True in the DAG definition parameter, which actually made it sequential execution of backfill runs. It slowed down the execution speed but got only 4-5  execution instance having incorrect xcom_pull data  in 365 execution instance. Which I managed manually.